# Can DecisionTreeClassifier be used with both binary and multiclass labels simultaneously?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can I fit the classifier with binary and multiclass labels to predict a result?

Multiclass labels can have more then 2 values, binary labels only can have 2.

Example (the first parameter in X is multiclass, the second is binary - [-1,1]):

```
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, -1], [2, 1], [1, -1] ]
Y = [0, 1, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
clf.predict([[1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing labels (usually represented with `Y` variable as you also do in your example) with features (the matrix `X` in your example). When talking about binary or multiclass labels, it's the output/response variable `Y` that is usually meant.

The input variables (values in matrix `X`) can be arbitrary integers or floats, so your example is perfectly valid.

Comment: If your input variables code multinomial values (i.e. 0='black', 1='red', 2='green') it might be better to binarize them first, instead of feeding them to the classifier directly.